# WPF Bind User Control property not working

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I have a user control and im trying to bind one of its properties

#### User Control Xaml

```xml
<UserControl x:Class="pi_browser.Testing.Example"
             ...
             x: Name="LabelControl">
    <StackPanel x:Name="RootStackPanel">
        <Label Content="{Binding Text, ElementName=LabelControl}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

#### User Control Codebehind

```cs
public partial class Example : UserControl
{
    public Example()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ExampleViewModel vm = new ExampleViewModel(State);
        DataContext = vm;
    }

    public Boolean State
    {
        get { return (Boolean)this.GetValue(StateProperty); }
        set { this.SetValue(StateProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty StateProperty = 
        DependencyProperty.Register("State", 
            typeof(Boolean), typeof(Example), new PropertyMetadata(false));
}
```

#### Main Page View Model

```cs
class ExampleViewModel
{
    public ExampleViewModel(bool v)
    {
        val = v;
    }

    bool val;

    public string Text { get => val ? "This worked" : "This didnt work"; }
}
```

#### Main Window Xaml

```xml
<Window x:Class="pi_browser.Testing.Tester" ... >
    <Grid>
        <local:Example State="True"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

In this example I didn't bind the State variable, I only passed a literal, but ideally I would like to bind to actual values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`State` is a boolean, yet you bind to `Text`. Let us fix one issue by creating a dependency property `Text` on your User Control. We shall fix the `Text` issue and not the boolean `State` issue. Once you fix that, do the same for `State`.

So to fix `Text` we need to fix why this fails:

```
 <Label Content="{Binding Text, ElementName=LabelControl}"/>
```

You set the `ElementName` to be the UserControl itself, which is what one wants. But then you tell the binding to look for (*remember binding is just reflection of an object under the covers*) the property `Text`. The property `Text` **does not exist** on that instance/class...but `State` does. Its obvious to bind to a newly created `Text` dependency property **on the user control** to fix the first issue.

---

Then when you instantiate the control on your main page, you need to then, and only then bind to `Text` because that property **also** resides on your viewmodel.

So three things, *along with the change mentioned on the UserControl*:

1. Make your ViewModel adhere to `INotifyPropertyChanged` and make the `Text` property use the notification mechanism you install.
2. Make sure that your main page has its `DataContext` set to a vailid **instance** of your ViewModel class.
3. Bind to `Text` such as `<local:Example State="{Binding Text}"/>`

Once that is done, the `Text` value will properly flow towards the UserControl.

Comment: Also be aware that `DataContext = vm;` in the UserControl's constructor will effectively break any DataContext-based Binding of its properties. E.g. `<local:Example State="{Binding SomeBooleanViewModelProperty}"/>` will not work as expected. A UserControl that exposes bindable properties must not explicitly set its own DataContext.